# alsamixer not detecting "Channel"

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

when I run the command as a `alsamixer` even if I run it as a root it does not detect the channels at my systems
this is all the columns that I get. sounds is working on my system,
but I have the feature of surrounding sound only can be enabled when channels active to 6 channels

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does `speaker-test` work with 6 channels?

Comment: @CL. I'm not sure about how many channels ...but on Windows I can control the channels on Linux I can't  ..definitely I have channels . ..but the Channels bar does not appear ..you can check my screenshot .

Comment: I did not ask about `alsamixer` but `speaker-test`.

Comment: speaker is working with Ubuntu...I just don't have the channels